# Nuclear waste reclamation

Tags: energy

Is it possible to reclaim nuclear waste from commercial reactors for useful purposes, if not necessarily energy production?

Comment: What kind of "useful purposes" are you thinking of?

Comment: Is this question (v1) a physics or a shopping question?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that is referred to as [reprocessing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_reprocessing).  It has been done in Japan and many other places.  Recovered plutonium can be used for nuclear weapons or reactor fuel.

Comment: Indeed, an old school friend of mine used to work for [the company that reprocesses fuel in the UK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BNFL).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to reprocessing and the extraction of plutonium as stated before, other possible uses would be: 
Extraction of strontium 89 for medical uses

Extraction of palladium, rhodium and ruthenium for chemical catalysts.

Use of the spent fuel rods as heat source. The radioactive decay of the fission products in a fuel rods produces significant heat for many years.